# Design NISQ Circuit with StrawberryFields

Tags: programming, quantum-circuit, photonics, nisq, strawberryfields

I am trying to design this circuits with strawberry fields. However I could not connect my first and second qubit mode:

[image]

orange boxes are beam splitters, blue boxes are phase shifters. The green box is nothing. (There was a letter of brand so I wanted to close it)
First two lines corresponds to 2 modes of my first qubit: Let's say: 0_a and 1_a and the other two lines corresponds my second qubit modes Let's say 0_b and 1_b

My code is here:

```
  prog = sf.Program(4)

with prog.context as q:
    ops.BSgate() | (q[0], q[1])
    ops.BSgate() | (q[2], q[3])
    ops.Rgate(0.5719) | q[0]
    ops.BSgate() | (q[0], q[1])
    ops.Rgate(-1.9782) | q[1]
    ops.BSgate() | (q[0], q[1])
    ops.Rgate(-1.9782) | q[2]
    ops.BSgate() | (q[2], q[3])
    ops.Rgate(-1.9782) | q[2]
    ops.BSgate() | (q[2], q[3])
eng = sf.Engine("fock", backend_options={"cutoff_dim": 5})

prog.print()
#prog.draw_circuit(tex_dir='./circuit_tex', write_to_file=True)
```

My result is here

[image]

and indeed I could not make this connection:

[image]

Any help for me?
Am I writing to correct code?

Answer (score 1):

Ok It is done and it is correct. I just forgat to give an initial state to the program  like

```
Ket(initial_state) | q
```

And after that I also added a BSGate for 1 and 2 mode